# How often does google analytics update the traffic data

Tags: google-analytics

I searched the internet but I couldn't find an explanation on how often the traffic data get update in Google analytics.

It doesn't seem to be real-time and I have seen few posts mentioning 3 hours delays.

Can you please share your experiences?

Comment: Maybe off topic, but still helpful.

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=enProcessing 

Latency is 24-48 hours. For standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now it is real time: [What’s happening on your site right now](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html)

Comment: Is advertising a commercial product against the rules?

Answer (score 7):

They do it several times a day but you should only rely on data that's over 24 hours old to ensure its accuracy.

Comment: has anyone got a reference to the official documentation?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen it less than 30 minutes in some instances.  We have created a service ([InboundLinkAlerts](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com)) based on the Google Analytics API which detects new links to your site.  Periodically I will do benchmarking tests and have found Google Analytics to report the new links within 30 minutes.

I have read there can be higher latency the larger your site (i.e. the more GA data you have).

Answer (score 0):

I read some where long back as they update the records every 2 Hrs